# React navigation stack navigator inside of a modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible for showing a stack navigator inside of a React Native modal ?
Let say i have login screen, and i want the whole registration process (registration form, email verification, etc.) done in a modal.

The flow will go like:

Login screen -> Registration form (inside a modal) -> email verification (still inside a modal) -> Done

When I click done, I want the modal to be dismissed. So the registration form and email verification will be dismissed with the modal.

Is it possible to do it with React-Navigation ?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you need is to make a new Custom Navigator. `StackNavigator` cannot do that for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627291/react-navigation-stack-navigator-inside-of-a-modal

Comment: @val do you know an example?